# can you use connectorx with SQL SERVER?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql-server, connection

I am trying to reduce the loading times to extract a database from SQL SERVER. I have read a lot about this library but no matter how hard I have tried I have not been able to connect, can someone tell me if this is possible or guide me to configure it, thanks.

try using pyodbc config

Answer (score 0):

[per this discussion, at least some support has been added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74967574/connect-python-polars-to-sql-server-no-support-currently)

I used sqlalchemy's urlib to make urls: and since url objects do not have a split() method, I cast to string.

```
connection_url = str(sqlalchemy.engine.URL.create("mssql",database=database, host=servername,
                                              username=username,
                                              password=password,
                                              query = {'driver':'SQL Server'}))
```

I then used `connectorx.read_sql(connection_url, 'select * from sys.databases')` to validate the connection worked.

It worked for my system's sql server authentication database connections but failed to login for Windows Domain Authentication.